# Saxon XdmNode.axisIterator() on "." node

Tags: java, saxon

I have an XdmNode that I need to get the first child node/attribute of from a specific XPath describing the sub node/attribute. So I do the following:

```
XdmSequenceIterator iter1 = ((XdmNode)node1).axisIterator(Axis.CHILD, new QName(subKey));
```

This works great for a subKey of everything except "." For that case iter1.hasNext() returns false.

I can instead, for this one case, do the following:

```
XdmSequenceIterator iter1 = ((XdmNode)node1).axisIterator(Axis.PARENT, new QName(((XdmNode) node1).getNodeName().getLocalName()));
```

But this strikes me as something that could bite me in the okole later.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:** Say I have the XPath "/Order/Dates/Date" and want to get the nodes back in Date order. So my XPath select gets me the list of nodes. I then walk those returned nodes to sort them. For each node I call axisIterator() to get the value. The value is that node so "."

**Update #2:**
At present to sort the results of a query, we read in all the results to a ArrayList and then call sort with a compare() method, as follows:

```
private void sortNodes(ArrayList<XdmItem> nodes, final String sortKey, final boolean sortIsAttr, boolean descending) {
    Comparator comparator = new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object node1, Object node2) {
            if (node1 instanceof XdmNode && node2 instanceof XdmNode) {
                if (sortIsAttr) {
                    return ((XdmNode) node1).getAttributeValue(new QName(sortKey)).compareTo(((XdmNode) node2).getAttributeValue(new QName(sortKey)));
                }
                else {
                    XdmSequenceIterator iter1 = ((XdmNode)node1).axisIterator(Axis.CHILD, new QName(sortKey));
                    XdmSequenceIterator iter2 = ((XdmNode)node2).axisIterator(Axis.CHILD, new QName(sortKey));
                    if(iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {
                        String val1 = iter1.next().getStringValue();
                        String val2 = iter2.next().getStringValue();
                        if(parseableAsDouble(val1) && parseableAsDouble(val2)) {
                            Double val1Double = Double.parseDouble(val1);
                            Double val2Double = Double.parseDouble(val2);
                            return val1Double.compareTo(val2Double);
                        }
                        Date val1Date = parseAsDate(val1);
                        Date val2Date = parseAsDate(val2);
                        if(val1Date != null && val2 != null)
                            return val1Date.compareTo(val2Date);
                        return (val1.compareTo(val2));
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            } else {
                return ((XdmItem)node1).getStringValue().compareTo(((XdmItem) node2).getStringValue());
            }
        }
    };
    if(descending){
        comparator = Collections.reverseOrder(comparator);
    }
    Collections.sort(nodes, comparator);
```

And the above works great unless the sortKey = ".". That's because "." is not a child of a node, it is the node. So to make this work is the solution to, for this one case, call ((XdmNode)node1).axisIterator(Axis.PARENT, new QName(((XdmNode) node1).getNodeName().getLocalName()))?

**Update #3:**
And now my proposed work-around doesn't work. Which is weird because the parent does have that node as a child.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't understood the problem. What is "." here? This method doesn't have any concept of a focus or context item. Could you explain more clearly what is the input document, what you are trying to achieve, what code you have written, and how it fails?

Comment: @MichaelKay - I just added an update. Please let me know if I need more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding. When you navigate the tree using Java iterators, you are binding Java variables to nodes: there is no XPath context involved, and no concept of ".".

Comment: @MichaelKay - I added more info to my question. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If the sortKey is given as ".", you can just extract the string value of both nodes using XdmNode.getStringValue() and then compare the string values using the same heuristic logic as you use for child nodes.

Alternatively, why not use the XPath engine itself to evaluate the sort key, rather than trying to interpret it yourself?

Construct an expression something like

```
let $x := string(" + subKey + ") 
return if ($x castable as xs:double) then xs:double($x) 
       else if ($x castable as xs:date) then xs:date($x) 
       else $x
```

evaluate it for both nodes, and compare the results using `XdmAtomicValue.getUnderlyingValue().getSchemaComparable().compare()`

Something like this (untested):

```
private void sortNodes(ArrayList<XdmItem> nodes, final String sortKey, XPathCompiler xpc, boolean descending) {
    final XPathExpression computeSortKey = xpc.compile(
       "let $x := string('" + sortKey + "') 
        return if ($x castable as xs:double) then xs:double($x) 
        else if ($x castable as xs:date) then xs:date($x) 
        else $x");
    Comparator comparator = new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object node1, Object node2) {
            if (node1 instanceof XdmNode && node2 instanceof XdmNode)           {
                XPathSelector selector = computeSortKey.load();
                selector.setContextItem(((XdmNode)node1);
                XdmAtomicValue key1 = (XdmAtomicValue)selector.evaluateSingle();
                selector.setContextItem(((XdmNode)node2);
                XdmAtomicValue key2 = (XdmAtomicValue)selector.evaluateSingle();
                return key1.getUnderlyingValue().getSchemaComparable().compare(
                   key2.getUnderlyingValue().getSchemaComparable());
            } else {
                return ((XdmItem)node1).getStringValue().compareTo(((XdmItem) node2).getStringValue());
            }
        }
    };
    if(descending){
        comparator = Collections.reverseOrder(comparator);
    }
    Collections.sort(nodes, comparator);
```

However, I think it would probably be better not to mix Java and XPath in this way, but rather to do the whole thing in a single XQuery expression.

Comment: What/where do I put that? Is that a subsequent query I run? And what object do I run it from?